# What is the value of the commutator $[\vec{S}, H]$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, commutator

What is the commutation relation between   $[S, H]$
where Hamiltonian $H= - \vec{S} \cdot \vec{B}$ , $\vec{S}$ is the spin and $\vec{B}$  is the magnetic field.

I am getting $0$ but it seems wrong.

Comment: Remember, $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{B}$ are vectors.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion your equation (the original version, before someone edited and added arrows) $$H=-S\cdot B$$ is incomplete,
because it hides the fact that $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{B}$ are vectors
and $\cdot$ is the scalar product between two vectors.
A better way to write the equation would be $$ H=-\vec{S}\cdot \vec{B}.$$

So your task is to calculate the commutator
$[\vec{S},H]$ which is short for calculating
the 3 commutators $[S_x,H]$, $[S_y,H]$ and $[S_z,H]$.

Instead of giving out the complete solution to you,
I will only sketch the route to go.

Begin with the $x$-component:
$$\begin{align}
[S_x,H] &= [S_x, -\vec{S}\cdot \vec{B}] \\
 &= [S_x, -(S_xB_x + S_yB_y + S_zB_z)] \\
 &= \text{ ... (use simple algebra and the commuation rules between $S_x, S_y, S_z$)}
\end{align}$$
You will see that the result is not $0$.

In a similar way you can calculate $[S_y,H]$ and $[S_z,H]$.

Finally, try to summarize the 3 results from above as one vector equation
$$[\vec{S},H] =\ ...$$

Comment: "Your equation is incomplete" is a bit exaggerated. At graduate level and beyond we really don't bother with arrows anymore, or hats for operators.

Comment: @Jamal Ah, interesting. When I studied physics (Germany, 1980'ies)
we actually continued to use the arrow on vectors all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yeah i forgot to mention that S and B are vectors.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch It's mostly because by graduate level you're expected to be knowledgeable enough to know from the context.

Comment: @JamalS In the particular case of “dot products” like $\vec L\cdot \vec S$ one often does keep vectors to make it clear there’s a sum involved.  Likewise for $\hat n\cdot \vec \sigma$.  Granted in a lecture those are often skipped because instructors are lazy bums but I would wager most textbooks still keep those around.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I agree. Most textbooks still keep the vector notation,
but nowadays mostly by using boldface instead of an arrow.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch In the end it varies, but just picking a random graduate math text for example, Fuchs and Schweigert, I see they don't use anything to distinguish vectors.